# How to escape a variable in a string, PowerShell

Tags: powershell

In my code, I try to keep a command in a string; to then pass it as a parameter to Invoke-Expression. But the variable is evaluated before

```
$command = "Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.Id -lt 1 }"
Invoke-Expression $command
```

I tried: `$$`,`\$` ...

Comment: i see you have 2 solutions currently, so this is an aside ... DO NOT use `Invoke-Expression` if you can avoid it. for the reasoning behind that, look up `SQL injection` ... it can get nasty if you aint really, _really_, REALLY careful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The escape sequence character you're looking for is the backtick (`` ` ``)!

From the [`about_Quoting_Rules` help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules):

> To prevent the substitution of a variable value in a double-quoted string, use the backtick character (`)(ASCII 96), which is the PowerShell escape character.

```bsh
"This string contains a `$dollar sign that won't be expanded"
```

---

> In my code, I try to keep a command in a string; to then pass it as a parameter to Invoke-Expression

As a general rule of thumb, **don't do that** - you'll end up handing control over what code executes in your script or function to the calling user.

In your example, simply executing the code directly should suffice:

```bsh
Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.Id -lt 1 }
```

If you have *a specific use case* you can't figure out to rewrite without `Invoke-Expression` then please update the question with it :)

Answer (score 2):

You should replace the double quotes `"` by the simple one `'`

```
$command = 'Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.Id -lt 1 }'
Invoke-Expression $command
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the typeacceletator `[scriptblock]` for `System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock` and create this way

```bsh
C:\> $command = [scriptblock]::Create('Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.Id -eq 3320 }')
C:\> invoke-command $command

 NPM(K)    PM(M)      WS(M)     CPU(s)      Id  SI ProcessName
 ------    -----      -----     ------      --  -- -----------
     27    27,49      25,77       0,14    3320   1 ApplicationFrameHost
```